# Doctrine2 finding an entity that doesn't exist

Tags: doctrine-orm

What happens if in Doctrine2 I do the following with an entity manager.

```
$object = $em->find( 'MyModel\User', -999 );
```

Is object false, is it a User object, does an exception get thrown? Basically, how can I test if a row exists in the database based on some criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Doctrine2 manual,

The return value is either the found entity instance or null if no instance could be found with the given identifier.

[Doctrine Manual Entry](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-primary-key)